# How to fetch cookies from a logged in website in Chrome, using nodeJS for Web Scraping?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, cookies, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from https://internshala.com/student/dashboard using NodeJS. I somehow found that this website creates an `API` for student data. I am able to fetch the API data by sending `POST` request to `https://internshala.com/student/paginated_applications` using `request` library. But I need to send a **cookie** along with it in the header which I have to copy from chrome developers tools from networks section, for which I have to login first in my browser. 
I want to automate this login feature, I tried a lot but couldn't come up with a solution. I even tried to login by sending login credentials using POST request to `https://internshala.com/login/verify_ajax/user` but that also gives error.
How do I achieve automation?

Comment: What have you tried? If you read the docs I'm sure they show how to set a header.

Comment: I tried to set all the headers but I get an error as CSRF The action you have requested is not allowed